# GUI for Argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, argparse

I'm using a simple argparse function to in my python script :

```
def get_args():
    """Get CLI arguments and options"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='AngioTool File Analyzer',
                                     formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument('rootPath',
                        help="path to files for the experiment",
                        action=FullPaths, type=is_dir)

    parser.add_argument('-c', help='string to specify the control device to which all devices should be ratioed', default='D1')
    parser.add_argument('-p', help="list of fields to plot",
                        default=['Total Vessels Length', 'Total Number of End Points', 'Total Number of Junctions'])
    parser.add_argument('-i', help='string to specify first interval', default='min')
    parser.add_argument('-t', help='comma serperated list with chart titles to be placed on charts', default="Chart 1, Chart 2, Chart 3")
    parser.add_argument('-V', action='version', version='%(prog)s 1.0', help='print version number')

    results = parser.parse_args()

    return results
```

My goal is to wrap up my code and distribute the program to a few people using py2exe and py2app.  I've run across a few modules which, in theory, make it easy to generate a UI from the argparse code rather then having to make the users interact with the command line.  Unfortunately, the tools I've found (argparseui, gooey) require tools that are a bit of a pain to deal with (e.g. pyQT4 and wxPython) and don't support Python3.

Are there any other modules to achieve this a simple UI from argparse with more mainstream dependencies?

Comment: What do you want with the gui?  Just one txt field where can type a commandline clone?  Or mulitple fields and buttons?  Or how about browser based input?  Your argpsrse usage is simple.

Comment: I'd say Qt and PyQt/PySide are fairly *mainstream* dependencies, but I agree that they can be difficult to distribute, especially on windows.  If you don't want to deal with distributing dependencies, the only GUI toolkit that's part of the standard library is [Tkinter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html), though it's fairly basic compared to Qt

Comment: `PyQt` supports python 3.  There are [downloadable binaries](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download) for python 3.4 at least

Answer (score 5):

There is also [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey)! <del>I've yet to use it</del> I've used it once, and it's pretty amazing; it even has File Selector widget.

[image: File Selector Animated Gif Example]

***Disclaimer***: I've taken this from [an answer in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41088923/484127)

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't want to depend on any third party libs like pyqt then you should consider some tools using tk like this https://github.com/codypiersall/cligui

Comment: I'm opposed to third party libs as long as they support python3.  I simply couldn't get arparseui to work because it needs pyQT4 and that just doesn't seem like it's available anymore.

Comment: tried using `cligui` and modifying main to be `# Parse the command line inputs
    results = get_args()

    cligui.CliGui(results, None)

    rootPath = results.rootPath
    first_interval = results.i
    ctrl_device = results.c
    plot_key = results.p
    chartTitle = [x.strip() for x in results.t.split(',')]`  I get `AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute '_action_groups'`

Comment: Error messages and code chunks don't format well in comments.  Edit your original post.  And with the error, post enough of the traceback so we know where the error is occurring.  `argparse.parse_args` produces a `Namespace` object, but I have no idea of what would expect it have this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

- [gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey)

  - old project, more-or-less active
  - only argparse → wx
  - many features: widgets, layouts
  - some bugs. for example, the entry file must be a python script = no python module, no bash script. bash scripts may work with the option `requires_shell=True`
- [Cli2Gui](https://github.com/FHPythonUtils/Cli2Gui#comparison-to-similar-projects)

  - new project
  - very basic, no fancy features
  - multiple backends: pysimplegui (tcl/tk), qt, html
  - multiple frontends: argparse, optparse, ... (for Cli2Gui, this is more important than many features)
- [cligui](https://github.com/codypiersall/cligui)

  - old project
  - alpha version